# How to change image based on the Boolean value, where Boolean value is stored in database and image is store in the angular file

Tags: angular, ionic4

In my angular project, I should display some image if the database value is true and display other image if the database value is false. I don't know how to bind Boolean value to the image

I tried adding string interpolation to fetch Boolean value in the image path in Angular. I am getting Boolean values in the console, but the image is not changing

```
<img src="assets/imgs/{{walkingBeam.HomePosP}}.grey-dot.PNG">
```

I expect grey-dot.PNG to be displayed if the Boolean value is false, and display red-dot.PNG if the Boolean value is true.

Comment: you can also create the image path from ts and bind that var into img src, and in your html code PNG is also capital please check your image name ans extension

Comment: Why not wrap that markup in some kind of `if`/`else`?

Comment: @YashRami, Thanks, for the response.I created image path in ts file but it din't work

Comment: @NicoHaase, Thanks for response, Can you please explain in detail like how to do?

Comment: What about checking the given answers? If one of them does not work as expected, share what you've tried (as in: share the **exact** markup!)

Comment: I am getting image by using if/else and by hard coding the boolean value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this.

In component ts file.

```
imageUrl: any;
check: boolean;
ngOnInit(){
  if(this.check){
     this.imageUrl = 'assets/imgs/' + walkingBeam.HomePosP;
  }else{
     this.imageUrl = 'assets/imgs/elseimage.png';
  }
}
```

In HTML file

```
<img [src]='imageUrl' />
```

Update:

If you want to read property from DB, you need create a service and use in component.

```
@Injectable()
export class ImageService
{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {    
  }

  GetImage(id) {
    return this.http.get('/api/image?id=' + id);
  }
}
```

In your backend, you need create an API by `Spring Rest API` or `ASP.NET Web API` to read your property.

This is a prototype for `ASP.NET Web API`.

```
[Route("api/image")]
 public string GetImage(int id)
 {
      // handle your logic to get image url
 }
```

In the component ts file

```
constructor(private imageService: ImageService){
}
 ngOnInit(){
      this.imageService.GetImage(id).subscribe(data => { 
         this.imageUrl = data;
     });
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I am getting image when i hard code variable check to true/false.

Comment: How to bind it with database property, and fetch value of the database??

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use ternary operator

let say your boolean value is stored in variable named `flag`

> In your Html

```
<img *ngIf="flag"  [src]="setImagePath(flag)">

<img *ngIf="!flag" [src]="setImagePath(flag)">
```

> In your ts file

```
setImagePath(flag) {
    let imagePath;
    imagePath = flag ? `assets/imgs/${walkingBeam.HomePosP}.greydot.PNG` : `assets/imgs/${elseImagePath}.greydot.PNG`   
     return imagePath;
   }
```

**OR** simlpy use ***ngIf** with string concatenation concept

```
<img *ngIf="flag" [src]="'assets/imgs/'+walkingBeam?.HomePosP+'.greydot.PNG'" alt="">
<img *ngIf="!flag" [src]="'assets/imgs/'+elseImagePath+'.greydot.PNG'" alt="">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am getting Boolean value from database in the console. But the image is not displaying .